# How to connect LDR to LED by using battery 5V

Tags: transistors, ldr

I connect LDR to LED by using battery 5V like this circuit.

[image]

I adjust value of VR and LDR but it's not work. LED still 0.00V.

How to fix circuit for make LED to 5V

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem: -

[image]

The potentiometer is only 100 Ω. Try something like 100 kΩ instead.

You also need a resistor in series with your LED to limit the current when the transistor eventually turns on.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 0.7V on the base of Q1. Put a meter in to measure the voltage at the base of Q1 and adjust RV1 to see what the range of voltage is.

If RV1 is a 100 Ohm pot you might possibly need to replace it with a larger value. LDR1 may range from several megaohms to a few hundred ohms. However the circuit values look reasonable so the best check is to measure the base voltage of Q1.